# I need to validate mobile number using regx

Tags: php, javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate mobile number

it should only start with 9 8 and 7.
data type should be integer
it should be of length 10.

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you search for it on Google or somewhere else?

Comment: What about country codes? My autocomplete in Chrome frequently adds +44 to the front of my number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution that satisfies your criteria.

```
$isOk = preg_match("/^[789][0-9]{9}$/", $number) ;
```

Also, you may later cast it to `int`:

`$number = (int) $number ;`

Also, this source contains a lot of examples: [LINK](http://regexlib.com/%28A%280lTSDq1QfcQAdFhno5HkHO9ajSYxnn_GKzHrz8aUf4TJyZUr-yHMJNdl-VOeGTIthfnAAiPBTfiwz_qAevZLlnm3_RR_LzVIfVNXRFYBd3AC6May6dG-Rgl1kkNA0EIwqlyf_WC5slJVDa7xcF925wYtyYFY5syTjbh8O6cX1P5iOSTwB6AoJUj8-mMA8-Op0%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to validate a number that meets your criterial

```
$regexp = "/^[987][0-9]{9}$/";
```